# Can Rails' CRUD get rid of the limitation of the default homepage path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't use the default home page path (def index) in controller#action, and set "def home" as the home page, and generate a new path "root_path" with `root "tasks#home"` in Routes.

This causes an Unknown action (The action 'index' could not be found for TasksController) error when I execute "Delete" on the home page. That said, Rails still considers "index" to be the legitimate home page, not "home". My "delete" hyperlink in View is:

```
<%= link_to "Delete it" , task_path(task), method: :delete, data:{ confirm: "R U sure?" } %>
```

If I change the above link alone, changing "task_path" to "root_path", the problem will not change.

Now I'm going to change the Controller, I'm going to change "tasks_url" to "root_path":

```
  def destroy
    @task = find_task

    if Time.now < find_task.due_date
      @task.destroy
      redirect_to tasks_url, :notice => I18n.t(:task_kill)
    else
      redirect_to tasks_url, :notice => I18n.t(:task_close)
    end
  end
```

After the change, a new error Routing Error (No route matches [DELETE] "/") is thrown.

Unless I cancel the custom homepage path in MVC and Route and change all to index, this problem cannot be solved. Am I really unable to customize the homepage?

### Heading

The following are the key routes:

```
tasks GET    /my_tasks(.:format)   tasks#index
      POST   /my_tasks(.:fo## Heading ##rmat)   tasks#create
new_task GET    /my_tasks/new(.:format)    tasks#new
edit_task GET    /my_tasks/:id/edit(.:format)      tasks#edit
task GET    /my_tasks/:id(.:format)    tasks#show
     PATCH  /my_tasks/:id(.:format)    tasks#update
     PUT    /my_tasks/:id(.:format)    tasks#update
     DELETE /my_tasks/:id(.:format)    tasks#destroy
root GET    / tasks#index
```

Comment: I still don't understand why you think `root "tasks#home"` will actually change the output of the `tasks_path` helper and the question is just more ranting then actually telling us what you want to accomplish. Show us your routes.rb and a list of what routes you actually expect to route to what.

Comment: this is my routes, I hope my homepage is "root_path" https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsTYe.png

Comment: When asked please add the code to the question as text. Screenshots of code are not ok in any context as they can't be searched/copied etc.

Comment: I hope the "redirect to" of ```def destroy``` will point to "home" instead of not finding index.

Comment: @max stackoverflow has a limit on code length. In this example, Screenshots can show complete routes.

Comment: Dude, that's a lame excuse. And thats not how things work here. You should not have any problem fitting the relevant code into the limit. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: ok I edited the roues infos

Answer (score 0):

The "limitations" here are all in your head. Rails is extemely convention driven but if you want to get off the Rails and do things your way you're free to do that (if this is actually a good idea is a another discussion).

You're really muddling things up with your concept of a "home page" which is an irrelevant concept in Rails. The `root` macro simply routes the `/` path to a controller and action and defines the `root_path` helper. It does not change a completely unrelated path helper.

If you want `things_path` to route to `/` the straight forward way is to just declare it manually:

```
root '/', to: 'tasks#index'
get '/', to: 'tasks#index', as: :things
resources :tasks, 
  path: 'my_tasks',
  except: :index
```

The duplicate definition of the `/` path is simply to generate both the `root_path` and `things_path` helpers. Rails will just match with the first one anyways.

But since the conventions assume that `things_path` will also give you the route for creating the resource you're going to be breaking your forms and you'll need to manually specify the URL:

```
<%= form_with(model: @thing, url: @thing.new_record? ? '/my_tasks' : thing_path(@thing)) do |form| %>
```

Comment: IMHO you should just change tasks_url to root_path where relevant instead of making a mess.